# How to add Credentials of the server

Tags: perl, windows-xp

I am very new for perl and we had very emergency requirment. I need to convert the bat file code into Perl script code. I am confused, how we add credentials in Perl.
In bat file: I have the above sample credentials

How can I change the above credentials in Perl. How to write the above credentials in Perl script.Help is very much appropriated

Comment: What have you tried? Also, your code does not look like a credentials file but rather like a command line. It appears the credentials are stored in `C:\catcredentials.properties`. What exactly are you trying to achieve in Perl?

Comment: The above file is Dos commands which executes in bat file, I want to convert the above commands into perl.Firstly i need to login into server abd give soe credentials ,then beed to create a new report and load the data into a file

Comment: Good. But you provided only an example usage. I'm bad at reading minds. To implement a replacement in Perl, you would need a thorough specification of the server (how should requests look like) and the report protocol. Reading the source of the tool you are using on the command line could help. But why are you trying to replicate a working tool anyway?

Answer (score 2):

To execute an external command, you probably want to use the `system` built-in. It will not capture the output, however:

```
system "program", "-argument", "value", "-argument2", ...;
```

before using it, you should read the [whole documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) and also look into [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html), [`qx{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) and [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), for different nuances.

If your requirements are more complex, you should look into the IPC family of modules on [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/).

Comment: System is used to run in CMD.exe file not to login into server. Hear i need to login into server using the above credentials. can you please help me how we connect to server and add the above login credentials. Something like this "http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/catalog_manager"

Comment: @user178900 **If** your script is a working batch file, **then** wrapping the command into a Perl `system` call will produce *identical* functionality. **Else, if** you want to connect to the server on the HTTP layer (which is not the application layer here), you are probably interested in the [`LWP` library](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP.pm). However, this would require more information on the authentication methods used. **Else**, I have no idea what you are talking about and you need to rephrase your requirements.